# Does compactness give measurable function any special property?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, soft-question, compactness, measurable-functions

Let $X$ be a metric space, $f:X \to \mathbb R$ continuous, and $g:X \to \mathbb R$ Borel measurable. If $X$ is compact, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. If $X$ is compact and $f$ locally Lipschitz-continuous, then $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous. This means compactness "strengthens" continuity. I would like to ask if this phenomenon happens for measurability, i.e.,

> Does $g$ have some stronger property in case $X$ is compact?

Comment: @EricWofsey Exactly.

Comment: I think it's unlikely, because we can easily remove one point from $X$ making it non-compact. This point would have significant impact on continuity (because we still have restriction on how $f$ can behave in neighborhood of this point), but has almost no impact on $g$. For measure, more important property is local compactness.

Comment: Interesting! Can you provide such an example? (we can easily remove one point from $X$ making it non-compact) @mihaild

Comment: Take any compact that has limit point, and remove this limit point - new space is no longer compact. For example, remove any point from $[0, 1]$.

Comment: How about this: if $g$ is locally integrable wrt some measure, and $X$ is compact,  then $g$ is integrable.

Comment: Compactness doesn't really strengthen continuity. What it does is allow you to show that local properties are global properties, provided that when the property holds on two open sets, it also holds on their union. Even uniform continuity is an example of this (can you figure out why?) As with Ruy's example, this applies to local properties of measures just as well as it applies to local topological properties.